# sympy seems to fail solving a system of non-linear equations while being able to solve them separately

Tags: python, sympy, equation

I'm trying to find the points `(x,y)` where the first derivatives of a funtion `f(x,y)` are zero. The function is `f = x * log((y^2)/x) - x*(y^2) + 3*x`.

If I try solving the system of equations in sympy I get the answer `(x,1)` and `(x,-1)`, which I think means "whatever the value of x" and y either equal to `1` or `-1`. The code can be seen below:

```py
    import sympy as sp
    x, y = sp.symbols("x y", real = True)
    f = x * sp.log((y**2)/x) - x*(y**2) + 3*x
    sp.solve([f.diff(x), f.diff(y)],[x,y])

    :> [(x, -1), (x, 1)]
```

If I try solving the derivative of f in relation to y first, for y, I get as a result [1,-1] as expected. :

```py
    sp.solve(f.diff(y),y)

    :> [-1,1]
```

Then if I try replacing y by either 1 or -1 in the expression of the derivative of f in relation to x and then solve for x I get as result:

```py
    sp.solve(f.diff(x).subs(y,1),x)

    :> [E]
```

The pairs `[E,-1]` and `[E,1]` are the solutions for the system of equations. But why sympy can't give me these pairs of values when I try solving the system of equations initially?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Please report on GitHub: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the system-solver fails, but if you use `manual=True` you can get your solutions:

```
>>> eqs=[f.diff(x), f.diff(y)]
>>> solve(eqs,manual=1)
[{y: -1, x: E}, {y: 1, x: E}]
```

Comment: This issue is being addressed in https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/22719